# sfml-network-2.dll was not found, не могу понять что забыл подключить

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sfml

Подключил все как было показано в этом видео https://youtu.be/Nb2RI48JH4g но выдает ошибку при запуске[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <SFML/Network.hpp>

int main()
{
  short int matrix[23][23];
  sf::TcpSocket socket;
  sf::IpAddress ip = sf::IpAddress::getLocalAddress();
  std::cout << ip << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Ошибка возникает как раз из-за того, что библиотеку подключили при сборке, а во время выполнения ее нет.

Comment: Скопируйте все `.dll`-ки в директорию с исполняемым файлом.

Comment: Больше спасибо, всё заработало)